# Exception during parsing

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to built a parser to parse through my dataset but an exception is raised . I am newbie and haven't used parsing much.

I can add arguments to parser but as soon as the function is built an exception is raised.

[The code I am trying is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PHJc.png)
[The error I am getting is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLaUT.png)

Comment: Can't run an image of code.  Put the text of the code in the question.  See the [mcve] guidelines to reproduce the error.  Include the full traceback of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct this error using
**args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()**